# How to override vendor/magento/module-import-export/Files/Sample?

Tags: magento2

I tried,

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\ImportExport\Files\Sample">
    <plugin name="change_product" type="\Test\Abc\Files\Sample" />
</type>
 </config>
```

Created folder Test/Abc/Files/Sample - In that i have uploaded file.
[image]

But its not overriding?

Comment: Could you share the code from your plugin class?

Comment: @Pmclain I am overriding this for Download Sample File as shown above.  In this Test/Abc/Files/Sample folder, csv file is uploaded